# Error in a changing delta angle radial coordinate system

Tags: actionscript-3

I feel like this has probably been asked/answered here, and if so, I apologize for the bandwidth, but I don't see any explanation.
The problem is as follows: 
I have 3 points .1 point (target) moves around 2 points (pointer). 3 point (ship) goes to 1 (target). I need to, at the angle α <90 degrees (Math.PI/2) 2 point (pointer) changed in the opposite direction.

Thanks!

```
function MovePointer(ship:Object, targ:Object, point:Object, R:Number, DAngle:Number):Number
{
    var angle = Math.atan2(point.y - targ.y, point.x - targ.x);

    if ( Math.abs( Math.PI-( angle - (Math.PI+Math.atan2(ship.y - targ.y, ship.x - targ.x)) ) ) < Math.PI/2 )
    {
            DAngle=-DAngle;
    }

    angle += DAngle;


    point.x = targ.x + R * Math.cos(angle);
    point.y = targ.y + R * Math.sin(angle);

    return DAngle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate the angle and rotation should leave your

```
 const product : Number = (point.y - targ.y) * (ship.y - targ.y) + (point.x - targ.x) *  (ship.x - targ.x);
if (product > 0) {
DAngle = -DAngle;
}
```